# Would you ever implement a linked list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about data structures formally for the first time. To me, some of the benefits traditionally described of linked lists (easier memory allocation and faster input and deletion to the body of the list) seem moot in js given the way arrays work (like objects with numbered keys).

Can anyone give an example of why I'd want to use a linked list in javascript?

Comment: When you need a constant time insert/delete.

Comment: NodeList is an example of a doubly linked list (with some array-like capabilities to boot).

Comment: I would implement (or use) a Linked List *if and only* if there was a *specific algorithm* that benefited from such - *and* the JavaScript overhead of the implementation was still insignificant to the gains. (But this is the same for using a Linked-List vs a 'normal' Array-List in just about any language.) The standard Array type with an *optimized native implementation* is "quite fast", even for middle-of-Array operations. YMMV as it will vary by implementation but often 1) It Just Doesn't Matter and/or 2) an Array-backed List is Just As Good Or better.

Comment: @zerkms but since the memory doesn't actually need to be shifted from insertion, do you really count the reference swapping?

Comment: There are reasons to use linked lists other than efficiency – say, if you want to insert elements in the middle of a list and keep references to other elements without having to keep track of their indexes.

Comment: @noob-in-need I'm not sure what you mean. Try (on a piece of paper) 
to insert something into a fixed-size array.

Comment: @zerkms It's my understanding that in a language like C an array represents a contiguous block of memory, and that in Javascript it does not. In Javascript, each index is not adjacent — in memory — to everything else in the list, and is not accessed by offsetting a number of bytes from the start. Therefore, they wouldn't need to move all of those bytes around on insertion or deletion. I'm a noob and am curious if redirecting the index references (that point to the values that don't move) is worth building out a linked list and leaving behind everything that comes with the array prototype.

Comment: @noob-in-need let's imagine we have an array with million elements. You want to insert something into the position with index `1`. It means you need to shift (reindex) `999999` elements to the right. How would you do that otherwise, without physically iterating over and changing values?

Comment: i would use something like http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/queues/ if i needed top-notch perf. run the test, and you cans see artifacts of your JS engine, like the 64k array switch...

Comment: See this article , it is very practical . https://blog.jcoglan.com/2007/07/23/writing-a-linked-list-in-javascript/

Comment: Interesting question, but I really can't imagine that using a Linked List versus an Array can possibly make that much of a difference, given the overhead of JS in the first place.

Comment: You don't need to implement a linked list if you write code in JavaScript but you definitely need to implement a linked list and many other data structures if you want to write a JavaScript interpreter.

Answer (score 20):

As the comments note, you'd do this if you need constant time insertion/deletion from the list.

There are two ways `Array` could be reasonably implemented that allow for populating non-contiguous indices:

1. As an actual C-like contiguous block of memory large enough to contain all the indices used; unpopulated indices would contain a reference to a dummy value so they wouldn't be treated as populated entries (and excess capacity beyond the max index could be left as garbage, since the `length` says it's not important)
2. As a hash table keyed by integers (based on a C-like array)

In either case, the cost to insert at the end is going to be amortized `O(1)`, but with spikes of `O(n)` work done whenever the capacity of the underlying C-like array is exhausted (or the hash load threshold exceeded) and a reallocation is necessary.

If you insert at the beginning or in the middle (and the index in question is in use), you have the same possible work spikes as before, and new problems. No, the data for the existing indices doesn't change. But all the keys above the entry you're forcing in have to be incremented (actually or logically). If it's a plain C-like array implementation, that's mostly just a `memmove` (modulo the needs of garbage collections and the like). If it's a hash table implementation, you need to essentially read every element (from the highest index to the lowest, which means either sorting the keys or looking up every index below the current length, even if it's a sparse `Array`), pop it out, and reinsert it with a key value that is one higher. For a big `Array`, the cost could be enormous. It's possible the implementation in some browsers might do some clever nonsense by using an "offset" that would internally use negative "keys" relative to the offset to avoid the rehash while still inserting before index `0`, but it would make all operations more expensive in exchange for making `shift`/`unshift` cheaper.

Point is, a linked list written in JavaScript would incur overhead for being JS (which usually runs more slowly than built-ins for similar magnitude work). But (ignoring the possibility of the memory manager itself introducing work spikes), it's predictable:

- If you want to insert or delete from the beginning or the end, it's fixed work (one allocation or deallocation, and reference fixups)
- If you are iterating and inserting/deleting as you go, aside from the cost of iteration, it's the same fixed work
- If it turns out that offsets aren't used to implement `shift`/`unshift` in your browser's implementation (with them, `shift` would usually be cheap, and `unshift` cheap until you've `unshift`-ed more than you've `shift`-ed), then you'd definitely want to use a linked list when working with a FIFO queue of potentially unbounded size

It's wholly possible all browsers use offsets to optimize (avoiding `memmove` or re-keying under certain conditions, though it can't avoid occasional `realloc` and `memmove` or rehashing without wasting memory). I don't know one way or the other what the major browsers do, but if you're trying to write portable code with consistent performance, you probably don't want to assume that they sacrificed general performance to make the `shift`/`unshift` case faster with huge `Array`s, they might have preferred to make all other operations faster and assumed `shift`/`unshift` would only be used with small `Array`s where the cost is trivial.

Comment: Can you give a concrete real world example where the advantages of a Linked List outweigh the disadvantages in JavaScript?

Comment: It's barely different in JS from any other language.The ability to use sparse `Array`s and delete from the middle of an `Array` really doesn't change the majority of use cases; most loops will assume all indices are filled so you can't pass the sparse `Array` to library functions. You still can't reliably ensure you can add to the middle of an `Array` in the general case without a massive amount of copying. The "advantages" of JS `Array` so rarely come up in practice that it's usually best to just treat them like a `vector`/`ArrayList`.

Comment: Really, the only difference is that the point at which you'd consider switching comes later in JS; in many other languages, the array-based list and linked list types are both implemented with equal efficiency. In JS, your handrolled linked list will cost more to write, and run even slower, so it takes larger algorithmic gains to justify it. Similar concerns arise in other high level scripting languages like Perl and Python which lack native linked list types. Basically, if the number of items is small (profile to define "small"), it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AdamZerner: JS does introduce one complicating factor: It's single threaded, executing JS code blocks the browser UI, but it's usually user event driven. So on the one hand, if the code runs in 1 microsecond or 10 milliseconds rarely matters; from the user's perspective, they were both instant. But if the overhead from `Array`'s "spikes" makes work sometimes go from 1 microsecond to 500 milliseconds, the page freezes while the code is running; switching to a linked list might make every usage take 500 microseconds, but a consistent 500 microseconds beats intermittent user visible UI freezes.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the inner workings in such detail. That is part of what I and the OP are asking. The other part is "what are some examples of real world use cases where it'd be worth implementing one".

Comment: I found the info at: http://blog.millermedeiros.com/linked-lists/ very useful to help better understand linked list usage in JS.

Answer (score 14):

I think there are some legit cases / reasons to prefer linked lists:

**Reason 1:**
As others already described, insertion and deletion operations perform fixed in O(1) time for linked lists. This might be a significant advantage depending on your problem.

**Reason 2:**
You can do things with linked lists that you can't do with arrays. This is due to the nature of a linked list -> every list entry has references to its follower (and predecessor if it's a double linked list).

*Example1:*

If you have a linked list of items, you could store a reference to a "currentItem" in a variable. If you need to access the item's neighbors you could just write:

```
curItem.getNext();
```

or

```
curItem.getPrev();
```

Now, you could argue that you could do the same with arrays while `curItem` is just the current Index. Basically this is true (and in most cases I would use that), but remember that in javascript it is possible to skip indices. So if your array looks like this, the index-method would not work as easily as thought:

```
myArray = [];
myArray[10] = 'a';
myArray[20] = 'b';
```

If you find yourself in that kind of situation, *maybe* a linked ist is the better choice.

However, if you need random access to the data (which is more seldom than it seems in most cases) you would go with arrays almost every time.

*Example2:*

If you want to "split" your list into 2 separate lists, this would also be possible O(1) time. With arrays you'd need to use slice, which is more imperformant. However, this is only an issue if you work with large datasets and perform this operation often. 20 repetitions of slicing of an array of 10 million strings took about 4 seconds on my machine, whereas the separation of one list into 2 took <1 second (providing you already have a reference to the list element where you want to start the separation of course!).

**Conclusion:**

In some cases you would benefit from a list's nature and it's performance. In some cases, you would suffer from it's imperformance (inability to randomly access multiple data).
I've never used a list in javascript, but similar structures like trees or graphs are used for data representation (in both backend and frontend javascript). So analyzing/learning list implementations in javascript is a good idea for more complex structures.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of concrete cases where a linked list would be preferable?

Comment: Hmm: suppose you have an array of customer names. For some reasons you might want the array to always be sorted. If you add a new customer name to your array you'd have to find the place where it would be inserted and then copy all elements after that index to their index+1 in order to get the free slot where you would put your new customer. If you do the same with lists you would just have to correctly set the two next-references of both the new customer and it's predecessor in the sorted list. User would only see differences when using large datasets and/or a huge number of insertions though

Comment: Couldn't you just do `array[array.length] = newCustomer` and not have to shift everything over?

Comment: array[array.length] = newCustomer would append the newCustomer at the end of the array. In the given example you want to insert the newCustomer somewhere inside the array, cause it's about maintenance of a *sorted* array. For example: array: ['Adam','Barbara','Carl'] and newCustomer would be 'Alex'. To maintain the sort order you'd need to insert Alex between Adam and Barbara. That's what the example was about. (Obviously you don't need sorted arrays/lists everytime :) It's just an example )

Comment: I'm not sure if #2 is a valid reason. It can be easily solved (e.g. with forEach() or for ... in) and arrays with holes are often considered bad practice.

Answer (score 7):

@noob-in-need I recommend you watch this video about the JavaScript garbage collector: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWmzxyMf2cE

In it he explains why using a linked list can give you finer-grain control over your code's speed (as ShadowRanger discusses in depth) and also prevent unexpected garbage collection slowdowns. Plus it was filmed on talk-like-a-pirate day. :)

Answer (score 4):

This boils down to the very basic differences of `array` vs `linkedlist`.

1. Inserting a new element in an array of elements is expensive, because room has to be created for the new elements and to create room, the existing elements need to be shifted. But for a linked list it's just change of references.
2. But reading and random access is easier in array than in linkedlist. Random access is not allowed. We have to access elements sequentially starting from the first node. So we cannot do binary search with linked lists.
3. Extra memory space for a pointer which is used to store reference for the `next` is required with each element of the list.

Answer (score 3):

It is surprisingly rare to find use cases where linked lists outperform data structures built on top of arrays:

1. Arrays tend to be more cache friendly and adding to the back is fast on average (`O(n)` worst case, but `O(1)` amortized)
2. The constant-time benefits of a linked list falls apart once you need to search for the location. So, if you need to find the location in the list, you can remove it in `O(1)`, but finding it is already `O(n)` and the array structure will most likely outperform linked list.

Still, scenarios exist where linked lists are used and where their constant-time operations shine. Schedulers are a good example because latency is important and guaranteed `O(1)` becomes a factor. Linked lists are used in the Linux kernel, but since you asked for a JavaScript example, the NodeJs runtime uses them for implementing timers:

- Timer (design & implementation): [`lib/internal/timer.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a506aa76a8cfb6438a0b4bc7604623bc6518a7c9/lib/internal/timers.js#L1)
- Linked list implementation: [`internal/linkedlist.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a506aa76a8cfb6438a0b4bc7604623bc6518a7c9/lib/internal/linkedlist.js#L1)

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find a simple comparison between `Linked List` and `Array`
Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Disadvantages

[image]