# How to insert and delete elements from an array by position, while updating positions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects with a position property along with other properties like this:

```js
[{position: 1, ...otherProperties}, ...otherObjects]
```

In the frontend, the objects are displayed and sorted by their position.

I am looking for JavaScript functions to perform the following operations:

1. Insert a new object at a specified position (e.g., before the element with position: 1) and update the positions of the other elements accordingly (e.g., previous position: 1 element will now be position: 2).
2. Delete an object from a specified position and update the positions of the remaining elements accordingly.

I am struggling with the creation of these functions

Comment: "I have tried to create a function that does something like this but couldn't get it." post that and describe your one challenge with that so we may best assist you here..  Not really enough details here to allow us to help you very well.

Comment: Adding/deleting elements at certain locations in an array covered by [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/splice).

Comment: Don't store the position as an object property since it seems you always want the position to reflect the index of the array anyway, or implement a [linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949981/would-you-ever-implement-a-linked-list-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two functions `addElement` and `removeElement` to add or delete elements in your array, while ensuring the positions are sorted correctly. For example:

```
function addElement(arr, newPosition, newElement) {
  // Add a new element at the given position
  newElement.position = newPosition;
  arr.push(newElement);

  // Sort the array by position
  arr.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);

  // Update the position of elements
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.position = index + 1;
  });

  return arr;
}

function removeElement(arr, positionToRemove) {
  // Remove the element from the given position
  arr = arr.filter(item => item.position !== positionToRemove);

  // Update the remaining elements' positions
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.position = index + 1;
  });

  return arr;
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = [
  { position: 1, prop: "a" },
  { position: 2, prop: "b" },
  { position: 3, prop: "c" },
];

let newArray = addElement(array, 1, { prop: "d" });
console.log(newArray);

newArray = removeElement(newArray, 3);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Please don't encourage poorly asked questions by attempting to answer them.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss edited the Q. Trying to be more welcoming :)

Comment: don't push if you know the index of insertion, just `splice()` and on removal you can do the same and only re-position from that index on.

Comment: Thank you @moshe for answer this helped me to fix my issue

Answer (score 1):

You need a method that parse all items of your array and set the new position to all of it.

```
function fixPosition(arr) {
  arr.map((o, i) => o.pos = i+1)
  return arr
}
```